# How do I deploy a Node.js app to a Azure App Service from Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-2019, azure-app-service-plans

I created a simple node.js express app that I want to host in an Azure Windows App Service.
The App Service resource was created successfully on Azure.
The project was created using the "Node.js Web Application" template.

**When I attempt to deploy from Visual Studio 2019, I get the following error message:**

> web.config not found in project, to create a project to deploy to
> Microsoft Azure you must create an Azure Node.js project.

Is there a different template I should be using?
If not, what the contents of the web.config file look like, so I can attempt to create it by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For deploying Node js Application to Azure you need to select
  `Azure Node js Web Application` Template.
- You have selected Node.js Web Application.
- If you select `Azure Node js App`, by default web.config will be generated.
- Copy the already created source files to the newly created Azure node.js Application.

[image]

#### Update

- ***You might not have selected Node.js development option while installing Visual studio.
  Click on the Install more tools and features option and select Node.js and update the VS***

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't see an Azure Node.js Web Application template in my VS 2019...

Comment: Type Node Azure in ***Search for Templates*** box.You can see Blank Azure Node.js Web Application.Select that template

Comment: You might not have selected Node.js development option while installing Visual studio.
Click on the Install more tools and features option and select Node.js and update the VS

Comment: @JohnB - Please check for the update in the answer.

Comment: @Harshitah I modified the current installation (even though I already had Node.js & Azure installed). I also did an update. Those project templates are now correctly appearing. Thx.